# Second monitor with no signal but VGA is connected, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have connected a second screen through VGA, but there is no signal (the 2nd screen is black). I have tried changing the resolution of the second screen, rebooting, etc, nothing is working so far. Help?

Here's the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2752 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1600x900      59.99*+  59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82    50.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 connected 1152x864+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00* 
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Other info:

- Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, 64 bit, 3.36.8, X11

Thanks!!

Comment: You start by saying "cannot connect" but then follow with "changing resolution", etc. It's far from clear what the problem actually is. Is the second monitor detected by the OS or not? If detected then what happens? And which is its native resolution?

Comment: Do you switched your monitor to VGA input ? Check other mode: `xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1280x800 --pos 0x0`

Comment: @ChanganAuto I apologise, I have corrected the question. The 2nd monitor is detected by the OS, but it gets no signal (stays black). Native resolution I think it is 1920x1080 (16:9).

Comment: Hi MMSilva. When it comes to hardware problems it's best to start at the start. First, ,make sure its's not a problem with the vga wire. Do you have another vga wire to test it? I use Debian with cinnamon desktop. If it were me I would go yo the start menu bar,open it and type Display". This would bring me to my displays and show me what monitors are connected to my machine.Does Unity desktop have a similar function? I've only used Ubuntu server so I'm not sure of the functionality of unity desktop. I hope you get it sorted out though.

Comment: @KevinMoore, the VGA wire is working, I tested with another screen. Yes, the monitor is connected to the machine, I can see it on "Settings > Displays". But it is not turning on (not receiving any signal, the screen is black)

Comment: Hi @MMSilva,Did you run the $lspci command to see if you can see if your system is finding your monitor?  Also try $dmesg to see if it is throwing up any errors when connected?